# What is the one word for different form of same thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am making a report over different database languages. I am curious to know if there is one word for representing different forms/variants of the same ting ?

Is "dialect" okay ?

say "SQL dialects" or "SQL variants" which one is more accurate, or is there is any other word better than this ??

Comment: In the context of slightly different programming languages, *dialect* is idiomatic. However, your question doesn't say that you're asking primarily about programming languages.

Comment: I am making a report over different database languages

Comment: That you should add to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of *programming languages*, the term *dialect* is idiomatic. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=SQL%20dialects%2CSQL%20variants%2CSQL%20dialect%2CSQL%20variant&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSQL%20dialects%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSQL%20variants%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSQL%20dialect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSQL%20variant%3B%2Cc0) confirms that *SQL dialect(s)* is much more common than *SQL variant(s)*.

> A dialect of a programming language or a data exchange language is a (relatively small) variation or extension of the language that does not change its intrinsic nature.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialect_%28computing%29)

Here are two examples of the use of the word *dialect* in this way:

- This page lets you specify which SQL dialects are used in your project. [- SQL Dialects, PhpStorm 2016.1 Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/sql-dialects.html); and
- The SQL dialect, derived from the Structured Query Language, uses human-readable expressions to define query statements. [- Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The word closest to an answer is in your question, though erroneous. It is [variant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/variant?q=Variant)